# Tratamento de exceção do tipo EOFError

Tags: python, python-3.x, exceção

```
while True:
    try:
        x = input().split()
        l.append(x)
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Estou com um problema nesse código onde não estou conseguindo obter um EOF do x, pois caso eu não digite nada e apenas aperte enter, mesmo assim ele recebe o valor e adiciona à lista. Gostaria de saber quais são os casos que o python retorna EOFError e como resolver esse meu problema.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atenção na identação do seu código, o bloco `try/except` deve ficar um nível abaixo do bloco `while`, veja só:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = input().split()
        l.append(x)
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Para sair do loop, ao invés de pressionar somente <kbd>Enter</kbd>, use <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> se estiver rodando o seu programa no terminal do Linux **ou** <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> se estiver no terminal do Windows (`cmd.exe`).

A exceção do tipo [`EOFError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#EOFError) é lançada pela função nativa [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) caso ela leia um [`EOF`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/EOF) a partir da entrada padrão (teclado).

Quando você pressiona apenas a tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `input()` não lança uma exceção do tipo `EOFError` pois leu algo **em branco**, que é diferente de um `EOF`.

Para fazer com que `input()` lance uma exceção do tipo `EOFError`, você precisa enviar um `EOF` para a entrada padrão pressionnado no teclado <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> em terminais Linux **ou** <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> para o console do Windows (`cmd.exe`).

A documentação descreve a exceção do tipo `EOFError` como:

> **exception EOFError**
>
> Raised when the `input()` function hits an end-of-file condition (`EOF`)
>   without reading any data. (N.B.: the `io.IOBase.read()` and
>   `io.IOBase.readline()` methods return an empty string when they hit
>   `EOF`.)

Referência [`EOF` e `Ctrl+D`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-Transmission_character)

Comment: Mas quando eu uso Ctrl+D no terminal ele simplesmente mostra isso: ^D, aí aperto enter e ele recebe esse valor como uma string, pode me ajudar?

Comment: @AngeloGonçalvesSalles: Certamente você está no console do Windows, onde o equivalente seria **Ctrl + Z**. Veja a minha ultima edição.

Comment: Ok, agora funcionou, muito obrigado, me esclareceu muito.